# Set cell height depends on the content of embedded collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static tableview. In a row, i am using embedded collection view controller.

I am trying to set row's height depending on the content of that embedded collection view controller.

I tried

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But it doesn't work.
Here is the screenshot of view on storyboard

[image]

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `tableView`'s delegate method to set the row `height`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 30.0 // Here you need to mention/calculate the content height of your collectionView and return it.
}
```

Comment: I already use it but can you show me how can i calculate collectionview height in delegate?

Comment: Just call `collectionViewContentSize` on your `myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout` property and you get the height and width of the content as CGSize.